# Trying to find lowest input entered but always evaluates to 0

Tags: c, variables

Goal is to have user enter numbers and print highest and lowest entered value. My problem is that the result always evaluates to 0.

I've tried declaring variables inside and outside of the main function. I'd rather keep them in the main function however.

I've also tried to have them undeclared and equal 0 but this just ends up giving me the same result.

```
float accumulate = 0;
int inpt;

    //While loop that lasts until while loop breaks. Printf outside of while loop because it's annoying.
    printf("Enter some numbers. Enter -1 to stop.\n");
    while (inpt > -1) {
        scanf_s("%i", &inpt);

        if(inpt < lowest & inpt > 0) {
            lowest = inpt;
            total++;
            accumulate += inpt;
            printf("%i\n", lowest);
```

If I enter 5, 6, 7, I expect the lowest integer to be 5 but it prints out 0

Comment: `(inpt < lowest & inpt > 0)` =>> `(inpt < lowest && inpt > 0)`

Comment: Uninitialized local variables will have an *indeterminate* value. It could be seen as almost random or garbage. And depending on the type, even reading such a value can lead to *undefined behavior*. Also initialize variables before you use them.

Comment: Consider posting those as answers to the questions.

Comment: Might also want to check input validation on that `scanf_s` call rather than assume it just worked and the user didn't type "fred" instead of a valid integer, lest you enjoy infinite loops and a file permanently in an undetected error state.

Comment: Where are `lowest` and `total` initialized? You need to show more of your code (it's an incomplete snippet to comprehend the problem).

Comment: They're initialized in the main function. I'd like to keep them there because I was told global variables are bad practice

Comment: And add `/W3` to the VS compiler string and do not accept code until it compiles without warning. You have to be consciously disregarding what the compiler is telling you is wrong to be working with the code you posted.

Comment: Please expand the posted snippet to a [mcve].

Comment: Initialize your minimum to `INT_MAX`, `SHRT_MAX`, `LONG_MAX` or other appropriate value defined in `<limits.h>`.  (Note that if you get -1 immediately, with no prior values, your maximum will be `INT_MAX` or other initialization value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there is no clear understanding in what are you trying there to archive.
As long as you have no `min` and `max` values to which you can compare it, you can try something like the following approach:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( void )
{
    int input   = 0;
    int min     = 0;
    int max     = 0;
    int flag    = 0;
    int i       = 0;

    while (  i < 10 ) // stop after 9 Inputs
    {
        printf( "INPUT = " );
        if ( scanf( "%d", &input ) != 1 )
        {
            printf( "Error,scanf()\n" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        if ( flag == 0 )
        {
            min = input;
            flag = 1;
        }

        if ( input > max )
        {
            max = input;
        }else if ( input < min )
        {
            min = input;
        }
        if ( min != max ) // Do not print if input is always the same.
        {
            printf( "\t\tlow = %d | High = %d\n", min, max );
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
INPUT = 5
INPUT = 6
        low = 5 | High = 6
INPUT = 7
        low = 5 | High = 7
INPUT = 4
        low = 4 | High = 7
INPUT = 5
        low = 4 | High = 7
INPUT = 1
        low = 1 | High = 7
INPUT = 2
        low = 1 | High = 7
INPUT = 8
        low = 1 | High = 8
INPUT = 7
        low = 1 | High = 8
INPUT = 3
        low = 1 | High = 8
```

Your program needs to know which number is `lower` and which number is `higher` if you have no numbers then you have to set them yourself.

Comment: Yeah I figured it out a little earlier. Thank you :)

Comment: Suggest you include `limits.h` and initialize `int min     = INT_MAX;` and `int max     = INT_MIN;` otherwise code will fail if values are all negative or positive as in either case one of the tests, e.g. `input > max` or `input < min` will never be true. (but still deserving of an UV for effort and well formatted answer)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I was thinking of doing that, but I was nut sure what exactly need to do the OP. Even now I am not quite sure :). That is the reason why I was informing the OP in the last part: `Your program needs to know which number is lower and which number is higher`.

Comment: Yes, no question clarity could have been better, but at least if you initialize the max to the minimum allowable by the type and the min to the max allowable by the type -- there is no way you could ever be wrong `:)`

Answer (score -1):

I don't really understand what a few of you guys are saying and that code I posted wasn't complete but if anyone is trying to have user input a bunch of numbers and have it return the lowest number,

I got around it by changing

```
if(inpt < lowest && inpt > 0) {
            lowest = inpt;
            total++;
            accumulate += inpt;
```

to

```
if(inpt < lowest && inpt > 0 || lowest == 0) {
            lowest = inpt;
            total++;
            accumulate += inpt;
```

This puts an OR operator that checks if lowest is set to 0 and will replace it with the first actual number entered